# Network programming achieving nowhere near benchmark

Tags: java, c, networking, performance, benchmarking

I've been doing some network programming using Java and C. So far I've only been able to achieve network speeds of around 15 MegaBytes/sec using different techniques and seemingly regardless of message size over loopback, remote networking also yields approximately the same speed.

Despite this I have used `iperf` to benchmark the network speed and it achieves 1.6 GigaBytes/sec. This is obviously a significant improvement. Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this speed in practical programming?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the numbers you give for iperf don't sound right.

1.6Gigabytes/sec = 12.8Gigabits/s.  That is beyond the 10Gigabit ethernet standard.
Perhaps you'd like to redo the numbers.

If on the other hand you have Gigabit ethernet then I would expect anything from 60-100 Megabytes/sec

The main factor under windows is the transmit and receive buffers.  If you increase those you'll see a dramatic increase in performance.
I'm not too sure how you do that in Java though.

Under C it's done like this (e.g. 1MegaByte buffer):

```
int sndbuf_size = 1048575;
result = setsockopt(thesocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndbuf_size, sizeof(int));
if (result != -1){
   socklen_t optlen = sizeof(sndbuf_size);
   if (getsockopt(native_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &sndbuf_size, &optlen) != -1){
        printf("  SO_SNDBUF: %d bytes\n", sndbuf_size);
   }
} else {
   printf("Error setting socket opt SO_SNDBUF (%d)\n", errno);
}
```

Make sure you call this for both send and receive buffers before you call listen or connect.
Note: if you call setsockopt with a value larger than the max, it won't fail.  To find out how big it really is after the call you have to call getsockopt with the same option.

EDIT: The other bottleneck could be your protocol or the disk.  However, if you're simply transmitting files through a socket with very little overhead like an HTTP server you should consider using the TransmitFile API under Windows or sendfile if you're using Linux.

sendfile() copies data between one file descriptor and another. Because this copying is done within the kernel, sendfile() is more efficient than the combination of read(2) and write(2), which would require transferring data to and from user space.

The TransmitFile function uses the operating system's cache manager to retrieve the file data, and provide high-performance file data transfer over sockets.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. iperf definitely says:
Server listening on TCP port 5001 
TCP window size:   256 KByte (default) local 127.0.0.1 port 5001 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 51816. 15.0 GBytes 12.8 Gbits/sec

Remember that this is me connecting to myself. I doubt there's much of a network overhead if it never leaves the host. (I can't display the lines iperf outputs so its copied and edited a bit).

Comment: Ok, the loopback interface is often memory to memory, not hitting the network card.  You an probably also increase the TCP window size.

Comment: Oops, got the terminology mixed. TCP window size is effectively the same as the send/receive buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: Bad ASCII art follows!

If your network pattern looks like the following, you'll never get really great speeds:

```
REQ   REQ   REQ   REQ   REQ
   RSP   RSP   RSP   RSP
```

What will get you some excellent speed is if you can achieve this:

```
REQ-A REQ-B REQ-C REQ-D REQ-E
     RSP-A RSP-B RSP-C RSP-D RSP-E
```

Several things can lock you into the first pattern. A single-threaded, single-state process. A multithreaded process with badly done locking.

You can get to the second pattern if you use asynchronous, multiple state networking or if you use really well done multithreading (or multiple processes).

You should try to avoid using a new TCP session per request/response if you can.  As each TCP session seeks its best rate it causes a mix of network overload and underutilization. Some new network protocols like SCTP are better. HTTP protocol options like pipelining are good as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* you're getting 1.6 Giga *Bytes* per second? That works out as 13 Gbps. Unless you're sitting on a core network switch with multiple optical links (and are somehow managing to *generate* that much traffic) I think there might be something wrong in your numbers somewhere.

Comment: I think when you're using the loopback address in this way your OS might be clever enough to use an optimized/"shortcut" path that effectively writes the "sent" packets straight into the "received" buffer. In other words, it's an in-memory operation.

Comment: I'll try using iperf between two machines. Give me a min. Although if the OS is doing that then why would my program not achieve the same speed?

Comment: OK. I just ran a few tests. First off: (laptop with Gigabit ethernet direct to laptop without Gigabit ethernet) 94.1 MegaBits/sec. Second: (laptop with Gigabit ethernet via router to server with Gigabit ethernet) 704 MegaBits/sec. By name alone Gigabit ethernet implies that could be around 1000 on a decent run. Why can't I actually send data at this speed?

Comment: Names can be deceiving. Firstly, "Gigabit" in comms terms means exactly 1000 Mbps, not 1024. So to begin with, when converting to megabytes/sec we get smaller numbers. Then you've got to factor in the overhead of the [link layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) plus the [layer 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Packet_structure) and [layer 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) encapsulations. And most importantly, you've got to take into account that (at least for TCP/IP) you can't keep blasting packets out without getting acks back.

Comment: Perhaps iperf is using UDP and your application is on TCP? That would make a *massive* performance difference. TCP can't proceed with sending packet _n_ until packet _m_ was acknowledged by the receiver, where _n_ - _m_ is the "window size".

Comment: Apparently: "By default, the Iperf client connects to the Iperf server on the TCP port 5001" source:http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php

Comment: I've got a Java NIO server running at over 200 MegaBytes/sec on loopback (client and server on the same machine). Using a modification of this tutorial: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/NewIOHelloServer.htm

Comment: It might be called gigabit ethernet, but don't forget there is protocol overhead and depending on the application other factors can come into play which can slow it down significantly.